# error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘FILE and ‘FILE* )

Tags: c++, linux, file

I am trying to get a file pointer by using pass by reference.
I have a `fileInterface` for mocking the code for Unit test.

**Function Definition for Actual Implementation:**

```
void openfile(FILE &fileFP)
{
    FILE *openedfileFP=setmntent(m_filename, m_mode);
    fileFP= openedfileFP;
}
```

**Function Definition for UT:**

```
FILE *m_fileFP;
void setfileFP(FILE * fileFP1)
{
    m_fileFP=fileFP1;
}
void openfile(FILE &fileFP)
{
    fileFP= *m_fileFP;
}
```

**Function Call:**

```
FILE *getFd = NULL;
TestFd=fopen(path,mode);
fileInterface->setfileFP(TestFd);
fileInterface->openfilegetFd(getFd);
```

When I compile I get the following error :

```
no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘FILE {aka _IO_FILE}’ and ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’)
         fileFP= openedfileFP;
```

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is hopeless: `void openfile(FILE &fileFP)`

`FILE` is an opaque type, so this might not even compile. It would depend on your compiler's library implementation. Even if it did compile you can't do anything useful with it.

What you're trying to do is to pass a `FILE *` by reference:

```
void openfile(FILE * &fileFP)
{
    FILE *openedfileFP=setmntent(m_filename, m_mode);
    fileFP= openedfileFP;
}
```

However it would be simpler to just use the return value:

```
FILE *openfile()
{
    return setmntent(m_filename, m_mode);
}
```